# Respond with a custom status code in validation process

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'd like to change the status code during the validation stage.

```js
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```

With these rules in place, if a request hits our endpoint with an invalid email property in the request body, the application will automatically respond with a 400 Bad Request code.

My question is, is it possible to change the status code from 400 to 422 (Unprocessable Entity)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create a [`Filter`](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) to catch `BadRequestExceptions` and transform them yourself to a 422. Whether you are looking to just change the status code, or the entire error response, you should have full access to the `res` object and be able to change things then.

Comment: Jay, what you're saying is, after creating a custom filter to catch `BadRequestExceptions` and make the status code to be transformed anything I want, then use it from controllers where it requires?

Comment: Yep, you just add the `@UseFilters` decorator to the controller that should return a 422 instead of a 400

Comment: This is all I can think of now. Thanks for an idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Since 7.0.6, Nest added the option of set globaly the default http status code for ValidationPipes.

Issue: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4393

Example:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
        new ValidationPipe({
          errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        }),
      );
```